# Why was calculus invented?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, math-history

Can anyone show me any flaw for which there was a need of inventing calculus or give me an example where normal maths fail and we need calculus?

Comment: To compute the are of a "complex" shape; see [Quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_(mathematics)). See [History of the Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus#History).

Comment: Limits provide concise approximations to expressions and formulae which would otherwise be computationally intractable.  The central limit theorem, the prime number theorem, the Poisson limit theorem, etc.

Comment: Newton needed derivatives to handle motion of bodies.

Comment: @Thoth, don't confuse *limits* with the calculus.  Limits are an important  technical tool but the main ideas of the calculus were formulated in a language that mostly avoided limits, though Newton's "ultimate" terminology was equivalent to them.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: limits do belong to calculus.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think we are in full agreement regarding that.  However I don't see how this is relevant to the OP's question.  Certainly calculus wasn't invented for the express purpose of introducing limits :-) Would you disagree?

Comment: @MikhailKatz: yes I would. The core of calculus is the introduction of infinity  in algebra. For instance by studing infinite summations, polynomials of infinite degree...

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Robinson was very good at polynomials of infinite degree.  In fact if recall correctly that's how he solved the [invariant subspace conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem). I know in France this is not very popular but try to relate to the idea that this is an international site.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: in what way does this comment contradict that calculus is not focused on limits and infinity ? Calculus is not "What happened when Newton was born".

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I think you hold an anachronistic notion of what the calculus is.  Numerous techniques for solving problems existed before calculus.  The way I interpret the OP's question is to know what the contribution of the calculus was that improved on the already existing techniques.

Comment: How else would we torture engineering undergrad students?

Answer (score 4):

This is actually an excellent question and at the time calculus first emerged in the 17th century in the work of Leibniz and Newton (in alphabetical order, without implying any priority), many top-level scholars were sceptical and in fact issued a number of challenges.  For example, [Huygens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christiaan_Huygens) adopted the position that the problems Leibniz can solve with the new calculus are no different from the problems one can solve with the old methods, and the difference is only in the language.  Huygens may have been at least partly right if he was referring to earlier techniques such as Fermat's [adequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adequality) which was indeed a powerful method that could solve many problems that today we typically think of as standard ware of the calculus: finding tangents to curves, maxima and minima, areas, centers of mass, etc. In fact, [Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph-Louis_Lagrange) considered Fermat to be the inventor of the calculus.

Half a century later, [Bishop Berkeley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Berkeley) was still vituperating against the new calculus, but the tide has clearly changed and the Fermat-Leibniz-Newton framework was an undeniable success in the hands of [Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler).

Something similar is happening today, with Abraham Robinson's "legalisation" of infinitesimals in his [1966 book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis).  Half a century later today, opposing voices are still being heard, but the tide is clearly changing, with high-profile advocates like Fields medalist [Terry Tao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terence_Tao) publishing applications and new insights based on Robinson's framework on an almost monthly basis.

Appreciating the advantage of the calculus over these earlier techniques involves detailed knowledge of the calculus and it is not that easy to give an elementary problem that can be solved by the calculus but not by Fermat's adequality, for example.  Using the calculus does simplify calculations significantly compared to the earlier methods.

One specific example that could be mentioned is finding the general tangent line of the cycloid curve.  Fermat was able to do it by means of an intricate geometric argument relying on his technique of adequality; see [this publication](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/10.1162/POSC_a_00101) for details.  Modern proofs using calculus are more straightforward.

Comment: What is your example problem ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, as I pointed out in my *answer* it is not that easy to give such an example, because of a fairly advanced state of the field even prior to the invention of the calculus.  More advanced problems related to tangents to curves, maxima and minima, centers of mass, areas, also variational problems would challenge the earlier techniques and demonstrate the superiority of the new calculus, as I suggest in my answer. Basically my point is that elementary problems *don't demonstate the superiority of the calculus*.

Comment: Try to prune this essay to provide a concise answer to the question posed by the OP.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, which parts should I delete?

Comment: It is not that easy to tell you, because as you know, I am not very versed in the history of Mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it was created to compute areas of regions enclosed by curves and to determine tangent and normal lines to curves.

Answer (score 0):

Invention of Calculus was in order to determine area under a curve and study the rate of change.

Answer (score 0):

What is the speed of a dropped stone after 1 second ?

Comment: This was known to Galileo I believe several decades before Newton introduced the calculus.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: this is calculus though. You can't address this problem without a concept of instantaneous speed. Who studied it in the first place is irrelevant.

Comment: I think that's a rather ahistorical remark, Yves.  It is only *today* that we automatically assign such problems related to parabolas to the domain of calculus.  Actually when I was in highschool this problem was solved without resorting to calculus because we hadn't learned it yet.  Motion under constant gravity I think is a counterexample to the necessity of calculus to solve concrete problems, and only reinforces the OP's question rather than answering it.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: the question is ahistorical. It is requesting a sample problem. It is about why, not who nor when.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I disagree with your comment.  The question clearly has a historical component related to the "invention of the calculus".

Comment: @jvdhooft: mh, I guess you misunderstood my contribution. The OP is asking an example problem that requires calculus. This is what my short answer is about.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed, your answer showed up without context. I removed the comment.